# Docker Windows container mounting named pipe

Tags: windows, docker, named-pipes

I'm trying to use Jenkins in a container and mount the named pipe to control the docker engine on the host. According to [this](https://blog.docker.com/2017/09/docker-windows-server-1709/) blog post it should be sufficient to mount the named pipe for this. However, when I run the container with that mount, the named pipe is not opened on the container hence, the docker client does not work.

Should I manually open the named pipe in Dockerfile? If so how is it done?

Here is a minimal repro without Jenkins (I have also tried installing docker plugin to Jenkins and docker client to container via chocolatey.):

```
Docker version 17.09.1-ce, build 19e2cf6
Windows version 1709, Build 16299.125
```

Dockerfile:

```
# escape=`

FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

SHELL ["powershell"] 
ENTRYPOINT [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("\\.\\pipe\\");
```

The commands to build and run:

```
docker build -t namedpipetest .
docker run -v \\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine namedpipetest
```

Output is:

```
\\.\\pipe\\InitShutdown
\\.\\pipe\\lsass
\\.\\pipe\\ntsvcs
\\.\\pipe\\scerpc
\\.\\pipe\\Winsock2\CatalogChangeListener-454-0
\\.\\pipe\\epmapper
\\.\\pipe\\Winsock2\CatalogChangeListener-124-0
\\.\\pipe\\LSM_API_service
\\.\\pipe\\eventlog
\\.\\pipe\\Winsock2\CatalogChangeListener-4b8-0
\\.\\pipe\\wkssvc
\\.\\pipe\\TermSrv_API_service
\\.\\pipe\\Ctx_WinStation_API_service
\\.\\pipe\\winreg
\\.\\pipe\\cexec-76
\\.\\pipe\\cexec-77
\\.\\pipe\\Winsock2\CatalogChangeListener-4f4-0
\\.\\pipe\\SessEnvPublicRpc
\\.\\pipe\\Winsock2\CatalogChangeListener-278-0
\\.\\pipe\\PSHost.131584061845916516.1868.DefaultAppDomain.powershell
```

Output of:

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' 3edad32c9f81

[{npipe  \\.\pipe\docker_engine \\.\pipe\docker_engine   true }]
```

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the same issue - and while I was investigating, I found that I needed to specify that tag to match my version of windows. For example, since I was using the `1803` build, I needed to use the `1803` tag for `microsoft/windowsservercore`. After that, I was able to see the pipe mounted successfully.

So really all I changed was

`FROM microsoft/windowsservercore`

to

`FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:1803`

In the blog post you reference, they do go out of their way to specify windows 1709, but don't seem to mention this issue. So maybe you're just missing a tag?

Comment: It seems that the issue was resolved in Windows 1803. However, I am still not able to connect the docker daemon on host. It is likely a problem with Hyper-V isolation. See [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36562) issue.

Comment: I was having the same issue, by thinking that I had to use `--isolation hyperv` - but realized that was just to get around the different windows versioned images failing for a different reason. After I started using the correct tag, I was able to stop using hyperv isolation and was able to mount the named pipe correclty